# ConTeXt scaled headline with hanging/protrusion

Tags: context, typography, context-mkiv, protrusion

I'm using `\scale` to scale  up a headline to the width of the entire paragraph, like so:

```
\def\scaleHead#1%
{\scale[width=\textwidth]{#1}}

\setuphead[subject]
[textcommand=\scaleHead]
\subject{Call me Ishmael.}

Some years ago—never mind how long precisely—having little or no money in
my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I thought I 
would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. It is a 
way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation.
```

My problem is that I would like the period at the end of the first line to hang, the same way I would get in the text body with `protrusion=quality`.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are scaling the headline -- including the period at the of it -- to `\textwidth` it will always fit and never protrude.

Comment: And Hans apparently told you so already: https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context%40ntg.nl/msg80133.html

Comment: My apologies. I got impatient. I posted Hans' answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I posted the same question on the ConTeXt mailing list and got an answer from Hans Hagen:

> that would only work if you typeset with a `\hsize` that is exactly the length of the title which in turn means that you have to adapt the font size and even then tex will probably squeeze the spacing first
>
> so the best is:
>
> `\subject{Call me Ishmael\rlap{.}}`

It isn't as pretty as the quality protrusion mechanism, but it works. Thanks, Hans!